# Is it possible to get the result of evaluating typeof (only) in c code with gcc or clang?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I have a `c` program that uses the keyword typeof. Is it possible to use the compiler to just evaluate all the `typeof(...)` expressions only, and generating the resulting code as the output, in a similar way in which the `-E` flag generates macro expansions?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Just for debugging purposes, you can always look at the generated disassembly. For example `sizeof (typeof(int)){0} == sizeof(int) ? puts("sizeof int") : puts("something else");` gives a disassembly only containing `.string "sizeof int"` and without comparisons/branches.

Comment: There is no “resulting code” of a `typeof` operator. The compiler does not replace `typeof` with other source code; it processes it internally. And I believe it has no switch for producing such source code.

Comment: In other words, `typeof` is a built-in operator, not a macro.  Note also that until C23, it is an extension, not part of standard C.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not a macro and that it was not present in old standards. But as such it refers to a specific type. For instance `typeof(int)` refers to the type `int`. So the question is if there is a tool to make those expressions to be replaced by what they refer to, given a program in c that contains some.

Comment: Any such tool would need to convert the `typeof` types after the preprocessing phase because `typeof` is mostly used within macro replacement text. Preprocessing is done in translation phase 4, but the type of the operand of `typeof` is not known until translation phase 7.